# "Autoconfig" and "Daemon" Tasks in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, daemon

My server guy wants to use apache, and also he wants to program a daemon to control automated file deletion, along with other automated file tasks.  Can node.js automate the deletion of files if they reach a certain length of time?  And in addition, can node.js time-stamp, because my server guy swears it cannot, and that "daemons are superior for automated file tasks!"

Thank you.

Sorry if my question isn't very comprehensible, I'm in a hurry to get this answered.

Comment: basically, can node.js replace daemons for file deletion, creation, renaming, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/fs.html#file_System) you can find how.

For such tasks, I think that cron job that executes some script (it can be a nodejs, php, perl, sh, whatever) can work just fine.

At the end, depends on your problem. Daemon sound like an overkill, but it might be the only approach.

Comment: but I don't understand how fs.unlink is used to delete files.  i thought it was used for removing LINKS to files, not remove the files, but also read that it was used for deleting files.  can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

One way to use node might be to use inotify/dnotify to be notified when files are created, then set callbacks with setTimeout to clear them, or keep a list and periodically iterate it and delete files.
The distinction between a daemon and node is not correct, a node application can be a daemon or a one-off script. Node just keeps running until no further interrupts are possible and then the script terminates.